# Let Cabal-Install show the install plan

Tags: haskell, cabal

If I install a package using `cabal install pkg` then `cabal` will install all packages that `pkg` depends on. If there is a conflict with already installed packages then `cabal` shows which packages have to be installed freshly, which ones are updated and which installed ones will be broken.
Is there a way to get this list unconditionally instead of running the install procedure?

Comment: `cabal install <pkg> --dry-run`?

Comment: How could I miss that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cabal install <pkg> --dry-run` will print the packages that will be installed without actually performing any of the installation. It will not show this information though if the package is installed or similar.